# How to get autocomplete with CSS Framework in VS Code when you installed them via NPM and exclude the node_modules folder?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, bulma, css-frameworks

For Example, if I want to get Bulma to my project via npm (recommended on the docs), I installed like this

```js
npm install bulma
```

And the files located in `node_modules`. And that is where problems happen.

Normally, I have excluded that folder in VS code for better performance.

And 2 extensions to display autocomplete for CSS on VSCode is `HTML/CSS support` and `Intellisense for CSS class names in HTML` will not support CSS file in that hidden `node_modules`.

( thanks to @garyking on [CSS files in folders excluded with `files.exclude` do not get parsed issue](https://github.com/ecmel/vscode-html-css/issues/68) to point out this propblem )

Do we have any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

My workaround are:

1: Show `node_modules` folder in VS Code again ( not good for performance as VSCode team said that )

2: Use this trick on VS Code setting.json:

```
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules/{[^b],?[^u],??[^l],???[^m]}*": true
  }
```

( more information, please check this issue [VS Code - Exclude all files except for...](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/869#issuecomment-630086813)